# HTTPS redirects for WordPress Multisite Network

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, https, multisite

I have a WordPress Multisite Network setup with multiple websites hosted on it.  I want to cover some of these sites with an SSL.  I have a SAN Cert installed on the server, that includes the domains that should be covered by the SSL.  I have the following rewrite rules in place but they only seem to work for the non-www http to non-www https redirect on domain1.org:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.org [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1\.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain1.org/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain2\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain2.com/$1 [R,L]
```

I have tried to change the `Site Address (URL)` (which updates the `Siteurl` and `Home` values for the site) for domain2.com to include the HTTPS, but this did not have any effect on the results.

In addition, now domain2.com is redirecting any request, including https, to the http version.  To try to resolve this, I have removed the re-writes for domain2.com and it continues to redirect all requests to http.

## Update

In an effort to resolve this, I removed the htaccess re-writes altogether, and changed the `Site Address (URL)` in the site settings to use the https url.  This worked for domain1.org, but domain2.com continues to redirect to http with every request.  Any reason why a multisite domain would do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this htaccess snippet. Also , you should change all the sites URLs to https.

Moreover, I would recommend uses this plugin ( https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/ ) to change all the links from http to https.

```html
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Regards,
Ed.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I understand the recommendation to put everything behind HTTPS, and that is the goal for this one specific site in the network.  We are working towards getting everyone on the network to have an SSL, but that is not feasible right now.  The re-write you gave me seems to do redirect any http request (regardless of domain) to http, which will not work for our current multisite network setup.  Is there a way to limit it to a specific domain?

Comment: @Eduardo Estevez Nunez Your .htaccess coding resolved my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have in wp_config.php?

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true)
```

Do you use some plugin for SSL?

Comment: I am under the impression that `FORCE_SSL_ADMIN` is only to make the admin use HTTPS, not the front end of a sub-site on the network.

I tried a plugin, but that created a redirect loop that broke the site in question, so I disabled it.